# size() returns 1 where matrix dimension should not exist

Tags: matlab

If I type `X = rand(2,3)` then `size(X,1)` and `size(X,2)` produce the expected results. If I type `ndims (X)` I get the expected two dimensions.

However, `size(X, k) == 1`, where `k` is any integer > 3. Why does this occur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This must happen, if the behavior of size is to be consistent. We think of a vector as of size 1xn or nx1. Of course the orientation is important, else MATLAB could simply tell you the vector is of length n. In the latter case, there is a trailing singleton dimension, so implicitly there are infinitely many trailing singleton dimensions. So that column vector is really of size nx1x1x1..., and a row vector is of size 1xnx1x1...

The same is true of a scalar. If the scalar is of size 1x1, then it must really be of size 1x1x1x1x...

Size must tell you the size of an object though, and where should it stop? I suppose if you were to redesign MATLAB from scratch, you might decide to not report any trailing singleton dimensions. So a column vector would be reported as of dimension n, but a row vector of dimension 1xn? To be honest, I actually prefer being told a column vector has dimension nx1. But then it must logically be of dimension nx1x1x1...

Anyway, long ago MATLAB did not allow you to index beyond two dimensions in arrays. Higher dimensional arrays have been here for at least 20 years or so, but there is still much legacy code that is still useful. (I've got code that I wrote over 25 years ago and is still in use.) You don't want to break existing code.

Comment: +1 for historical reasons why size should answer two elements by default even for a scalar

Answer (score 4):

Here is a visualization of a three-dimensional array. Call it `x`. Each "slice" through the array is a two-dimensional matrix.

[image]

You can see that `size(x,1) = 6` and `size(x,2) = 6`, and indeed `size(x,3) = 6`. The `size` function counts the number of cubes along each side.

Now consider what happens if we let `y` be a single "slice" of the array. It still has six cubes in the first and second directions, so `size(y,1) = 6` and `size(y,2) = 6`, but now each slice has only has one cube in the third direction -- so `size(y,3) = 1`.

This pattern is continued for higher dimensions (4, 5, 6, ...) although it's impossible to show those in a picture.

Answer (score 2):

`size(X,3)` is the size of the third dimension which in your case IS `1`. Try `X = rand(2, 3, 5, 23, 4,2, 6)` for example, now `size(X, 3)` should give `5`.

After all a 2D matrix is really the same a a 3D matrix where the size of the third dimension is 1

Comment: What I'm wondering is why the third (and fourth, and fifth...) dimensions should exist as trailing singleton dimensions. Why not simply stop at the two dimensions and make attempts to use size on the third dimension return an error message?

Comment: @user1205901 because if `size` strats to throw errors a **LOT** of existing code will stop working and all hell will break loose!

Comment: *a 2D matrix is really the same a a 3D matrix where the size of the third dimension is 1* is only true in a crazy world where, say, a scalar is the same as a `1x1` matrix ... oh, hang on, that's Matlab :-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Exactly! But I guess if a scalar can be a `1x1` matrix then it might as well be a `1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x....` matrix too :)

Comment: @user1205901 Why do you suggest stopping at two dimensions - why not one? Shouldn't a column vector also error when you try to get the size of its second dimension?

Comment: @SamRoberts It just happened that I first noticed this phenomenon today when I was working with a 2d matrix.