# 3D Matrix in Simulink which can be 2D is not supported

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, robotics, matlab-coder

I am using SIMULINK and I needed to define a Rotation Matrix 3,3,N where N is the number of Robots which I am trying to simulate. To do that, because I am also using the Simulink Coder I had to define the signal related to this matrix as **Variable Size** and I had to define the upper-bound in the following way:
[image]

The problem is that **when I want to use only one robot** (I set n_robots to 1) **I get the following error.**

*Cannot initialize dimensions of 'R' of 'test_pos_ctrl_target/rotation matrix to Euler angles' to [3x3x1]. When the number of dimensions of a matrix exceeds 2, the size of the trailing dimension must be greater than 1.*

Someone could help me?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the last dimension as `1` because MATLAB treats any matrix of dimension `[m,n,1]` as `[m,n]`. See [size() returns 1 where matrix dimension should not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292795/size-returns-1-where-matrix-dimension-should-not-exist) for more details.

Try defining `R` of size `[n_robots,3,3]` and then re-arrange the matrix inside your code (I assume you are using a MATLAB Function block).